# Call stored procedures from ZendFramework 3

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework3

How to call PL/SQL stored procedures in PHP Zend Framework 3?

I have a procedure which INSERTs into two different tables.
I want to call the procedure from controller after some action, but I didn't find any information in docs.

I tried to call procedure with `Zend\Db\Adapter`
but the code below doesn't work:

```
$dbAdapter = $this->valueTable->adapter;
$stmt = $dbAdapter->createStatement();
$query = "BEGIN PRC_SET_ETALON_NEED_UPDATE('$formData->currentCmMac'); COMMIT; END;";
$stmt->execute($query);
```

Comment: use prepare Statement. `$stmt->prepare(<proc call>)`

Comment: I want do it with ZF3 classes, because I don't to check how was worked procedure